# Most efficient way of finding a specific text out of string in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for the most efficient way of finding and returning a specific text out of a big massive string in JS.

> The rule of the specific text is a text that starts with `"ID_"` and ends
>   with `".pdf"`.

Assuming I'm having such a string (*short tiny version of it*):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_2556.pdf">Click here to
download.</a></li>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_37.pdf">Click
here to download.</a></li>
<li><a
href="/questions/237104/ID_29997.pdf">Click here to download.</a></li>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_0554.pdf">Click here to
download.</a></li>
</ul>
```

The script should return these separate values as strings:

> ID_2556.pdf
>
> ID_37.pdf
>
> ID_29997.pdf
>
> ID_0554.pdf

Comment: OK, what have you tried and why did it not work for you? And what is with the `json` tag? There doesn't seem to be any JSON here

Comment: How exactly do you define "most efficient / lightest"? What have you tried and have you measured it against your metric?

Comment: Do you actually have a Javascript string of HTML?  Or do you have that HTML content in a page?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty why did you remove the `node.js` tag? It seems relevant here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all matching strings with `String.prototype.match`:

```js
var html = `
<ul>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_2556.pdf">Click here to
download.</a></li>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_37.pdf">Click
here to download.</a></li>
<li><a
href="/questions/237104/ID_29997.pdf">Click here to download.</a></li>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_0554.pdf">Click here to
download.</a></li>
</ul>
`;

console.log(html.match(/ID_.*?pdf/g))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use regex for this task `/ID_.*?\.pdf/gm`:

Here is a playground: https://regex101.com/r/mD5Yt3/1

It will generate code for you:

```
const regex = /ID_.*?\.pdf/gm;
const str = `<ul>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_2556.pdf"><a href="/questions/237104/ID_2556.pdf">Click here to
download.</a></li>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_37.pdf">Click
here to download.</a></li>
<li><a
href="/questions/237104/ID_29997.pdf">Click here to download.</a></li>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_0554.pdf">Click here to
download.</a></li>
</ul>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `DOMParser` to turn the HTML string into a document, then select  `a`s which end in `.pdf`, figure out which ones fulfill the desired format, and push them to an array:

```js
const htmlStr = `<ul>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_2556.pdf">Click here to
download.</a></li>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_37.pdf">Click
here to download.</a></li>
<li><a
href="/questions/237104/ID_29997.pdf">Click here to download.</a></li>
<li><a href="/questions/237104/ID_0554.pdf">Click here to
download.</a></li>
</ul>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html');
const filenames = [...doc.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".pdf"]')]
  .reduce((filenames, { href }) => {
    const match = href.match(/ID_\d+\.pdf/);
    if (match) filenames.push(match[0]);
    return filenames;
  }, []);
console.log(filenames);
```

You could also do all the filtering inside the `reduce`, rather than in the selector string, if you wanted to reduce the code, might be a bit less efficient though:

```
const filenames = [...doc.querySelectorAll('a')]
  ...
```

Comment: Would that work on Node.js though? Judging by the OP's tags, we can't assume that he would have access to the DOM.